# Calculate the mode of the numbers in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to calculate the mode of this number

```
int data[] = new[24, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 32, 35, 37, 38, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45, 46, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 51, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 63, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 68, 70, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 80, 80, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 88, 89, 91, 91, 93, 96, 97]
```

I, have done some coding to find the mode of the number here is the code

```
public static void Mode(int numbers[]) {
    IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).forEach(i -> {
        IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).forEach(j -> {
            if (numbers[j] == numbers[i]) {
                ++count;
            }
            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                mode = numbers[i];
            }
        });
    });
    System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", "Mode is :  ", mode));
}
```

The above method return only one value as mode 53

However as per math logic the mode should be **53, 62, 67, 77, 78, 85**. I want to get the mode as above without using keyvalue pair (no Hashmap)

Please tell me how can I achieve this

Comment: How did you determine the mode "per math logic"?

Comment: Is my understanding that you should only tag a language that is being used, all I see here is Java, not C++.

Comment: Are the data always less than 100? If so, just use an `int[100]`, increment the in the slot for the value, and then scan across the array. With a small enough array size, it is fast enough.

Comment: no not necessary. the length is dynanic

Comment: @SanJaisy, the length isn't the question, the highest number in the data is the issue.

Comment: The occurrence of 53, 62, 67, 77, 78, 85 is same. So the mode is 53, 62, 67, 77, 78, 85. Please post the new code if you have solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption the highest number in the input data is some reasonable number, this code will find the modes. I'm sure there is a way to make it all Java 8 streams, but I'm still working to master them.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int data[] = new int[] {24, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 32, 35, 37, 38, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45, 46, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 51, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 63, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 68, 70, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 80, 80, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 88, 89, 91, 91, 93, 96, 97};
    final int MAX = 100;

    final int[] counts = new int[MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        int num = data[i];
        counts[num]++;
    }
    
    OptionalInt oi = Arrays.stream(counts).max();
    int cnt = oi.getAsInt();

    System.out.println("Modes for input data");
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; ++i) {
        if (counts[i] == cnt) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%3d", i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
```

Test Output:

> Modes for input data
>
> 53 62 67 77 78 85

Edit: the MAX can be found dynamically by doing something akin to the following. Again, the assumption is this maximum value is something reasonable, but the OP's question restricted the ability to use `Map` or similar objects.

```
final int MAX = Arrays.stream(data).max().getAsInt();
    
final int[] counts = new int[MAX+1];
```